# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error. ld: -r and -dead-strip cannot be used together

Tags: c++, xcode5, linker-errors, osx-yosemite, linker-flags

***XCode 5.0.1*** is giving me an error after successful compilation of 161 C++ project files.
**There were many Apple Mach-O Linker Error questions but none helped me.**

Message for the error is as following:

```
ld: -r and -dead_strip cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The linking section in my build setting is in the following image:

[Linker Section of XCode 5.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPau9.png)

Can anyone let me know how to solve this error?

**UPDATE**

When I set    `Dead Code Stripping` to    `No` the then I get 19 Linking errors. `Mach-O Type` is set to `Dynamic Library` for both `Release` and `Debug`.
Errors in this case are as following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar    _t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>,     std::allocator<wchar_t> > >,     std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t     const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>,     std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<wchar_t,     boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> >     >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<wchar_t,     boost::regex_traits<wchar_t, boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> > > const&,     boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_    t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>,      std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<wchar_t, boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<wchar_t, boost::regex_traits<wchar_t, boost::cpp_regex_traits<wchar_t> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >) in AdWrksTagDataFactory.o
```

And Error message as following:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In some similar questions I had seen that this might be due to more than one versions of Boost, but I already checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `Dead Code Stripping` to `No`. When this option is set to `Yes` Xcode will add the `-dead_strip` flag during linking which is **not supported** when linking relocatable binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already checked. It shows me 10 Linking errors.

Comment: What errors do you get? They might be unrelated to your original question.

Comment: I have updated them in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @d0mbn00b Honestly, these problems now look completely unrelated to your original problem, and might be subject of a different SO question.

Comment: I am getting different linking errors with different Linker Setting, Obviously. So At first I posted the one where I was getting minimum number of errors.